# Adding a column in multiple tsv file using awk

Tags: bash, join, awk, sed

I have two subdirectories named "Sample" and "Price". "Sample" consists one file named "1.tsv" while "Price" consists of >10000 tsv files named A.tsv, B.tsv ....and so on. I want to insert the 1.tsv into every file present in the "Price" directory before the first column.

Sample file in "Sample" folder: 1.tsv

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Samul | 25 |
| Alex | 36 |
| RDXC | 14 |
| Plut | 38 |

Sample file in "Price" folder: A.tsv

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Rajn | 39 |
| Maxo | 05 |
| DNDT | 11 |
| Maxi | 21 |

Sample file in "Price" folder: B.tsv

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Cars | 98 |
| Lint | 20 |
| Marq | 45 |
| DNSA | 17 |

and then c.tsv, d.tsv......etc

Output file: 1.tsv and A.tsv

| Name | ID | Name | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Samul | 25 | Rajn | 39 |
| Alex | 36 | Maxo | 05 |
| RDXC | 14 | DNDT | 11 |
| Plut | 38 | Maxi | 21 |

Output file: 1.tsv and B.tsv

| Name | ID | Name | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Samul | 25 | Cars | 98 |
| Alex | 36 | Lint | 20 |
| RDXC | 14 | Marq | 45 |
| Plut | 38 | DNSA | 17 |

and same with other files like 1.tsv and c.tsv, 1.tsv and d.tsv.......so on.
This is sample data, in reality, each file has around 56000 raws.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ for f in Sample/*.tsv; do paste -d'\t' Price/1.tsv "$f" > "$f".updated; done
```

Comment: Awesome, It is working perfectly. May I ask something, How I can learn awk? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you, Sumit